# Check if a select element has a specific class and add this class to a different div

Tags: jquery, html

I m using validation rules on my form so when someone doesn't select an option from a required select element, the form adds a new class "error" inside the select class like below:

```
<select class="Condition error" id="Conditionid" name="Condition" style="display: none;">
```

I want to check whether the selection has the class "error" and add it to a different div like that:

```
<div class="my-custom-select error">
```

How can i do that using jquery?

Comment: `$('.my-custom-select').toggleClass('error', $('#Conditionid').hasClass('error'))` http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   if($('#Conditionid').hasClass('error'))
    { 
       $('.my-custom-select').addClass('error');
    }
```

Comment: Is it also possible to do that without reload the page using Ajax ?

Comment: @Designer  yes you can

Comment: you can bind this to any event like button click,submit,onload,post,get

Comment: @ZPBaloch yes i want to bind it on button click. I 'm new in jquery

Comment: @Designer you can write these lines anywhere you want to add this class in juquery